# How to delete older log files from storm using TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy?

Tags: xml, logging, log4j, log4j2, apache-storm

I want to delete log files which are older than 3 minutes, wherein I am creating new ".log" files every minute using `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`.

Storm's **log4j2** folder contains **cluster.xml** and **worker.xml** files for its configuration. For the first case I tried creating new log files for worker-artifacts every minute and it's working , But when i tried deleting files which are older than 3 minutes using *Delete* tag and *ifLastmodified*, files were not deleted. You can see My XML file below:

```
<appenders>
    <RollingFile name="A1" fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}" filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-app${sys:logfile.name}">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${sys:storm.home}/logs/" maxDepth="10">
                <IfFileName glob="*app*.log" />
                <IfLastModified age="3m" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</appenders>
```

[Click to see my file system hierarchy and how files are created specially for worker logs here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uk9F.png)